visual-studio-code cmake: find_package failed for VTK
In VS Code, I use cmake to configure my project. The find_package failed：
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33812.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33812.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a configuration file for package "VTK" that is compatible
[cmake]   with requested version "".
[cmake] 
[cmake]   The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     D:/Thirdparty/VTK9.2.6/lib/cmake/vtk-9.2/vtk-config.cmake, version: 9.2.6 (64bit)
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!


The CMakeLists.txt: 9 (find_package) is:

I am quite sure my VTK package is OK, because I can configure it in cmake-gui. For example:

Why cmake-gui is OK, but vscode+cmake failed? How can I fix it?
Any suggestion is appreciated~~~

The key part of the error message is (64bit). It means, that the package is for 64-bit platform, but you build your project for 32-bit one.
